# C# Handling Exception in Task with await

Tags: c#, exception, async-await

I'm new to the `async` and `await` keywords in C# and I am using C# 6.0. What is the problem with my code? The DivideByZeroException does not get caught in the `catch` block. I read that in C# 5 and newer, exceptions can be handled easily with using `await` keyword surrounded by a `try-catch` block.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in try");                
        int result = await f(0);
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in catch");                
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in finally");                
    }
}

Task<int> f(int x)
{
    return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return 10 / x;                
    });

}
```

Comment: @CodeCaster while it looks similar, I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (at least in LinqPad). It prints "in try", "in catch" and "in finally". Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the catch block to see if it really is not entered?

Comment: @ckuri yes, you are right. I checked again. but the exception just get catched in release mode. in debug mode will not enter catch block! why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working in release, but since this is `WebForms`/`WPF` or `WinForms` app, it doesn't have console, so `Console.WriteLine` never prints anything. Replace:

```
Console.WriteLine("in catch");
```

with

```
textBox1.Text = "in catch";
```

This will work:

```
try
{
    textBox1.Text += "in try";               
    int result = await f(0);
    textBox1.Text = result.ToString();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    textBox1.Text += "in catch";                
}
finally
{
    textBox1.Text += "in finally";                
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to enter the catch block in Debug mode?

Comment: @HamidRezaAZ It will enter catch and after that finally block in both release and debug. Make sure you append text not replace it or just remove textBox1 from finally block